# Postfix outgoing email - Bad DNS PTR

Tags: server, 20.04, email, postfix

I have setup Postfix on Ubuntu 20.04 server but when sending an email out to one of the email address I get this error message below -

```
A2DC19FAFF: host mx00.1and1.co.uk[21.22.50.41] refused to talk to me: 
554-kundenserver.de (mxeue011) Nemesis ESMTP Service not available 
554-No SMTP service 554-Bad DNS PTR resource record. 
554 For explanation visit 
https://www.ionos.com/help/index.php?id=2425&ip=xx.xx.xx.xx&c=rdns
```

I tried to cc a Gmail address and I was able to receive the email to Gmail.

I just want to send emails out and don't want to receive anything back.

Its a new server setup and haven't changed main domain dns to point to this. Only setup a test domain. I thought its an issue with SPF record so added new server IP address into the TXT record which read as -

```
"v=spf1 include:_spf.mailhostbox.com a mx ptr ip4:old.ser.ver.ip ip4:new.ser.ver.ip ~all"
```

Any ideas how to get email working properly?

---

Also, when I checked email details on Gmail it showed sender as `localhost.localdomain`. I can see that postfix/main.cf has a hostname.

```
myhostname = localhost.localdomain
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, mydomain.com, localhost.localdomain, localhost.localdomain, localhost
```

What's the best practice to change this domain name? Do I just replace this value in `myhostname` above? or it's done via hosts file?

Answer (score 0):

Most mailservers check if a (correct) PTR exists as this is an effective way to filter spam from dynamic IPs.

So the only solution is to set the PTR for your server.

And yes, `myhostname` is the place where you configure the FQDN for Postfix.